# How do I get details about a package which isn't installed?

Tags: apt, dpkg, package-info

How can I get some details about a package without installing it, (eg. the description and version number) like in Synaptic or Aptitude. The command

```
dpkg -s PACKAGE
```

does not work, with this error. It works for installed packages, though

```
dpkg-query: package 'PACKAGE' is not installed and no information is available
```

Comment: With the [new apt command](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt.8.en.html), simply enter `apt show packagename` to get details about a package.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

For packages that are in your repositories you can use:

```
dpkg --print-avail PACKAGE_NAME
```

or

```
apt-cache show PACKAGE_NAME
```

or

```
aptitude show PACKAGE_NAME
```

or

```
apt show PACKAGE_NAME
```

Comment: Excellent answer that covers old and recent ways of get data from a package.

Answer (score 37):

The `apt-cache show` command can be used, instead of `dpkg -s`. Like this:

```
apt-cache show PACKAGE
```

([source](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/getting-information-about-packages-in.html))

Answer (score 8):

```
apt show
```

Or for more details

```
apt show -a
```

This will show only the description:

```
LANG=C apt show -a "$PKGNAME"|grep Description: -A99
```